Is it safe to view a solar eclipse with the naked eye during totality?
I thought I knew the answer to this up until today I read an article by an eye doctor who said one should keep the eclipse glasses on even during totality. Now I am somewhat confused. Can anyone explain why the sudden caution? I hope he is wrong but I saw this in two separate sources.
I was planning to wear my eclipse glasses until it is pitch black and then match the time to the expected time as a double check for safety. I would also only look for about 10 seconds so I don't get the edge of the moon sliding away from the edge of the sun. But still now I am wondering if this is really safe.

Related: Will just a glimpse (less than a second) of sun during partial solar eclipse damage eyes?. Also see the Related questions listed on this page

The moon completely blocks the Sun during totality.  So not only is it safe to view without the glasses, you won't see anything at all with the glasses on.

Is this question different from the question you asked a while back: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/55969/how-do-i-know-it-is-safe-to-remove-eclipse-glasses-when-viewing-a-total-solar-ec?

Does this answer your question? How do I know it is safe to remove eclipse glasses when viewing a total solar eclipse?

Please link to the article.  The answer given on your previous question is correct.  You wear the glasses until totality and replace them as soon as totality ends.  Unless you can provide the source of any other information this is a straight duplicate.

Yes, it's exactly the same question. Vote to close as dupe.

@Nilay Ghosh ...sorry but it is the same question. It's a dupe.

@Nilay Ghosh.  Sorry for confusion but you are right. It is the same question. I vote to make is a dupe. Thank you for pointing out. I had not noticed that. Sorry so much.

@James K Thank you I have straightened out my confusion. This is a dupe.

That eye doctor did not know what they were talking about. You will not see a thing through those eclipse glasses during the 30 seconds, maybe the last minute before totality. It is not yet safe to look at the Sun. Have a very good eclipse calculator & an accurate watch or clock. A cellphone that receives GPS input is an accurate clock. Input your precise location (lat, long, altitude) into the calculator and set an alarm for five to ten seconds prior to totality. Set this up hours in advance. Take the eclipse glasses off when they become useless. Then wait until the alarm goes off.

The risk is that if you take your glasses off too soon, or if you're staring at the Sun at the moment it reappears, you might suffer eye damage.  The tiny fraction of the Sun that's visible isn't bright enough to trigger your protective blink reflex, but it's still bright enough to cause damage.
During the core of totality, looking at the eclipse with the naked eye is safe.

Thank you Mark. Now I just pray the sun will shine during my totality  in the afternoon. There is a 50/50 chance of clouds right now but looking better by the hour that the sun will break through.

Some people say to keep glasses on during totality so just to be safe I will do that but am very thankful for your response.

You will not see a thing (not one thing) with your eclipse glasses on during totality. You will have a hard time seeing anything with your sunglasses on during totality. It gets very, very dark. The Sun's corona is a lot less brighter than is a full moon, and that is all that will be providing light.
